# Joining 2 tables into single query result

Tags: mysql, sql

Need some help with a query. I have 2 tables in a database, contacts & tasks.

```
mysql> describe contacts;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| contact_id | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| last_name  | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| first_name | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email      | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| phone      | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| school_id  | varchar(12)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| access     | char(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> describe tasks;
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| task_id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| task_name         | varchar(125) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| task_date         | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| task_description  | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| contact_id1       | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| contact_id2       | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| contact_id3       | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| contact_id4       | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| contact_id5       | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| contact_id6       | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| completed         | char(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want to get the info from the tasks table but I want to replace the contact_id1-contact_id6 with some of the fields from the matching contact_id. I have been messing around with nested select statements which will work but is very messy. It just seems there has to be a cleaner way to do this. I thought I had some with this,

```
SELECT tasks.task_id, tasks.task_name, tasks.reminder_time, tasks.reminder_interval, CONCAT (contact_1.first_name, " ", contact_1.last_name) as contact_1_name, CONCAT(contact_2.first_name, contact_2.last_name) as contact_2_name, CONCAT(contact_3.first_name, contact_3.last_name) as contact_3_name
FROM tasks
JOIN contacts contact_1 ON tasks.contact_id1 = contact_1.contact_id
JOIN contacts contact_2 ON tasks.contact_id2 = contact_2.contact_id
JOIN contacts contact_3 ON tasks.contact_id3 = contact_3.contact_id
```

But my issue here is that it is not showing tasks where any of the values of contact_id1-contact_id6 have a value of 0 which is the default value if no contact_id is set for it.

Any help you can provide would be great.

Comment: Please go and research normalisation before going any further

Comment: Does a `contacts` row exist with `contact_id = 0`? If not, what are you expecting it to return with your join condition?

Comment: do your joins like this `LEFT JOIN contacts contact_1 ON tasks.contact_id1 = contact_1.contact_id AND tasks.contact_id1 <> 0` this will keep all the records on the left table (tasks) and join with the contacts table when the contact_idX <> 0, if contact_idX is not found or zero, then all values in contact_X will be NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a view that does normalize the tasks table then the join will be easy. You can make a permanent view or just for the select.

The view would need somehow to be a UNION

```
SELECT task_id, task_name, task_description, contact_id1 as contact_id, completed from tasks
UNION ALL
SELECT task_id, task_name, task_description, contact_id2              , completed from tasks
UNION ALL
SELECT task_id, task_name, task_description, contact_id3              , completed from tasks
UNION ALL
SELECT task_id, task_name, task_description, contact_id4              , completed from tasks
UNION ALL
SELECT task_id, task_name, task_description, contact_id5              , completed from tasks
UNION ALL
SELECT task_id, task_name, task_description, contact_id6              , completed from tasks
```

So then it looks like this

```
WITH tasks_easy as (    
    SELECT task_id, task_name, task_description, contact_id1 as contact_id, completed from tasks
    UNION
    SELECT task_id, task_name, task_description, contact_id2              , completed from tasks
    UNION
    SELECT task_id, task_name, task_description, contact_id3              , completed from tasks
    UNION
    SELECT task_id, task_name, task_description, contact_id4              , completed from tasks
    UNION
    SELECT task_id, task_name, task_description, contact_id5              , completed from tasks
    UNION
    SELECT task_id, task_name, task_description, contact_id6              , completed from tasks
 )
 select *
 from   tasks_easy t
 join   contacts c   on (t.contact_id = c.contact_id)
```

Have not tested this, but should work like this.

Edit: Actually was thinking about it. UNION ALL, at least for the temporary view is not necessary. Probably will bring you some time improvement if your tables are real large.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. It is more clean then creating a bunch of nested select statements then joining them.

Comment: You are very welcome. Did it that way zillion of times in data migration projects taking over the data from old systems (historically grown or better said historically messed up systems) to modern systems. Sometimes it is unavoidable to deal with badly designed tables.

Comment: I have to admit that this db design is mine. I am more of a front end developer and am usually accessing a data service that someone has created. Any tips on how I could have better handled the linking of the contact and task tables when I first created them?

Comment: LOL. Sorry, did not want to be offensive then. Strictly by the book you would make a third table with the contacts to a task like `task_contacts`. Then you would have a primary key autoincrement and you would have two foreign keys. One foreign key being the task_id of the tasks table and one being the contact_id to the contacts table. Makes it more complicated but as you see in queries it can be helpful.

Comment: Ah I see. That layout would of also opened it up so I would not be restricted to just 6 contacts per task that I initially set. Next time I will need to spend more time planning the database structure. Thanks so much for all the helpful information.